# Ubuntu's C drive or system drive partition isn't showing

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

I've installed Ubuntu by watching a tutorial from internet. I had already dual booted Windows 7 and windows 10. so, I decided to install Ubuntu in the windows 10 drive to replace it with Ubuntu. So, I did it.Now when I start my computer it shows 4 menus from which I can select between Ubuntu and windows. But when I start my windows 7 and go to **my computer** I cannot see that partition/drive (i,e one of my partition that i used for installing Ubuntu isn't accessible from my windows 7). Now I want to uninstall my Ubuntu and want to get back that partition for using it to store my data or something else. please help me.[images to see what i'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugcUV.png)

Comment: Any Windows OS won't see or access other non Windows partitions, other than listing them as Basic.  This is Microsoft's problem.  If you wanted you could have a NTFS data partition that could be used from Windows and Ubuntu.  See mikewhatever's comment on removing.